# I add smart app banner to my website but it doesn't work on android

Tags: javascript, android, html

One line of code was enough for iOS. But I am having problem on android. I have attached the manifest.json file. There is only one button at the top. I want the application to write its name on the play store and show its logo. Code:

```
<button id="btnAdd"></button>
    <script>
  
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    deferredPrompt = e;
    btnAdd.style.display = 'block';
});

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    btnAdd.style.display = 'none';
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    deferredPrompt.userChoice
      .then((choiceResult) => {
          if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
              console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
          } else {
              console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
          }
          deferredPrompt = null;
      });
});


  </script>
```